# If Excel Is Open Then

Tags: vbscript

I've got a Sub that sets an Excel instance (below), within that sub I run a loop that sets off another sub.

```
Sub A
    Set objExcel    = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objExcelWb  = 
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Scripting\0711_Settlement2_Copy.xlsm")
    Set objExcelSht = objExcelWb.Worksheets("Test")

    rw = 2
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Do While objExcel.CountA(objExcelSht.Rows(rw)) > 0
        subDoWork objExcelSht.Rows(rw)
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

In that next Sub, I want it to run ONLY if the above Excel spreadsheet is open.  I'm using the following:

```
Sub subDoWork(rw)
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xlApp.Open = True Then

        'script main body

    Else
        subTerminateScript "Script Canceled"
    End If
End Sub
```

For whatever reason

```
xlApp.Open
```

does not work.  can anyone assist?

Comment: Unclear to me. You are opening a workbook and work with a sheet. You could add error handling there. When you call the second sub, you pass a `Range` object, there is no point in checking again there if the workbook is open, and neither in opening Excel again. You can just work with the sheet or the range object.

Comment: im a complete novice to error handling.  all im trying to do is prevent a WSH error from appearing if I close excel while I am reading and writing data from excel.  If I close excel while the loop is running I get:  "Object required: 'rw.Cells'  error.  I want to prevent that error from appearing, and I just want to run my subTerminateScript.  I can't figure this out!

Comment: As far as I know, the Excel application object does not have a Open property or method. If GetObect returns an object, excel is running. The Excel object also doesn't have CountA property, perhaps you intend to loop through workbooks or worksheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, you could wrap the sub-call into an error handler.

```
Do While objExcel.CountA(objExcelSht.Rows(rw)) > 0

    on error resume next
        subDoWork objExcelSht.Rows(rw)
        if err.Number <> 0 then
            msgbox "an error occurred at row " & rw & vbCrLf & err.Description
            exit do
        end if
    on error goto 0

    rw = rw + 1
Loop
```

VBA has `on error goto <label>`, vbs doesn't. So take care that `on error resume next` will still try to execute every line of code and does not stop on the first error.
If this is suitable depends on your actual code, eg. if you work on multiple sheets, if you need to continue the loop even after an error etc.